# In R, how do i include a forward slash in the name of a column?

Tags: r

While creating my data.frame, I want one of my columns to include a '/' in the column name. When I try to put it in normally, when I check my object, the '/' is replaced by a period. 
Here is the code I am working with. My problem is with the 'S/NS' column.

```
df_3 <- data.frame(age=numeric(7800),
                 duration=numeric(7800), 
                 value=numeric(7800),
                 'S/NS'=character(7800),
                 sex=character(7800),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

head(df_3) gives me the following output.

```
age duration value S.NS sex
1   0        0     0         
2   0        0     0         
3   0        0     0         
4   0        0     0         
5   0        0     0         
6   0        0     0
```

What I intended was for the column "N.NS" to appear as "N/NS" (smoking/non-smoking). I have tried fiddling around with the quotation marks, putting in a backslash escape before the forward slash, and some fruitless google searches. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `check.names = F` to disable name checking:

```
df_3 <- data.frame(age=numeric(7800),
                   duration=numeric(7800), 
                   value=numeric(7800),
                   'S/NS'=character(7800),
                   sex=character(7800),
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE,check.names = F)

> colnames(df_3)
[1] "age"      "duration" "value"    "S/NS"     "sex"
```